# How to find the nearest date

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, lambda, entity-framework-6

I have the chart with three precisions.

Per hour,
Per 30 minutes,
Per 15 minutes.

Table with my data looks like this:

[image: Data table]

When i generating my chart i starting from the special date time for example from current date time

For example. When I starting from 18:00, and my preccision is per 15 minutes i need data from this times

- 18:00
- 17:45
- 17:30
- 17:15
- 17:00
- ...

In my data table I have data maximum per 3 minutes, so when i would like to get data from 17:15 my lambda query returns null because i have data only from 17:13 and 17:16.

So i need the query whitch return data nearest my data time. In upper example it's need to return data from 17:16.

I try DiffHours Method but it's don't work on MySQL. I need method working on MySQL and MSSQL

My current method looks like this:

```
var report = _reportRepository.FindBy(a => a.Fridge.FridgeIdentity == fridgeIdentity && a.CreatedDate.Year == fromTime.Year && a.CreatedDate.Month == fromTime.Month && a.CreatedDate.Day == fromTime.Day && a.CreatedDate.Hour == fromTime.Hour).FirstOrDefault();
```

but it's work only for per hour precision.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Do you have a [time table](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/louis_davidson/archive/2010/02/04/creating-and-using-a-time-not-date-table-dimension.aspx) you can join to and aggregate against?

Comment: Do you need to be able to start from a random time or will it always be a multiple of 15 minutes? E.g. can your start time be 18:03:45 (and then you need then the closest time to 18:18:45, and so on), or do you always start at round values (18:00, or 18:15, 18:30, ...?)

Comment: dastination-data - I don't know how it's can resolve my issue, could you wrote me an example?

Comment: Solarflare - I always start from round values.

Comment: And a second question: your working report-code will only give you times AFTER your full hour, so if you have 17:59 and 18:03, it will give you 18:03 for 18:00. You said your report works correctly for full hours. Is that the case, do you not want to include past times? This would make it a lot easier!

Comment: No, because data is from my device, and this device sending report when someone touches them - so I can't control this

Comment: I still don't know the answer to my question: if you have two entries in your database with 17:59 and 18:03, and you want to query for 18:00: what should be the result? Your current code will use the entry 18:03. You said your code works for hourly querys. So please be precise! Which value should it take? And what if you have just the entries 17:46, 18:09 and 18:29 and want to query every 15 minutes: which value will it take for 17:45, 18:00, 18:15 and 18:30? And same question if you have the entries 17:46, 18:09 and 18:16.

Comment: "if you have two entries in your database with 17:59 and 18:03, and you want to query for 18:00: what should be the result?" The result should be the date nearest 18:00, so 17:59. My currently code use the 18:03 because i don't know how to get entry nearest 18:00, so i getting first entry where hour is 18. My current code works but not perfect nad only for hour precision. For example in my data table i have data from 8:46 to 9:26. If i need data for 9:00 query should return 12966 entry. If i need data for 9:15 entry should  return 12972 entry.

Comment: When i looking for entry from special time (for exapmle 18:15) query always need to returns entry which created date nearest my definied special time(18:15)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this, to get the closest time to a particular interval:

```
var fromTime = new DateTime(2016, 05, 20, 9, 0, 0);
var report = _reportRepository
             .OrderBy(m =>m.CreatedDate > fromTime 
                             ? m.CreatedDate - fromTime 
                             : fromTime - m.CreatedDate)
             .Take(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You showed only limited code and weren't utterly specific about some points even after several questions about it, so I will assume the following:

- you are able to create a working report for hourly precision, that means you are able to generate the list of desired times, e.g. 18:00, 18:15, 18:30 for a 15 minute interval (you just can't get the correct data for it) and these times are in the variable `fromTime`
- you always have round times as report times, so e.g. 18:00, never 17:48
- your closest entries can be both before and after the query time
- if you do e.g. a 15 minutes report, and there is no value in your database with a datetime between 17:45:00 and 18:14:59, the report will not have any result for 18:00 (since your data covers every 3 minutes, it shouldn't be a problem anyway, except for pauses)

You have to use different queries for the 3 interval times. For 15 minutes use (assuming your table is called `a`):

```
select *
from
(select *,
 convert(timestamp(date(date_add(CreatedDate, INTERVAL '7:30' MINUTE_SECOND)), 
         maketime(hour(date_add(CreatedDate, INTERVAL '7:30' MINUTE_SECOND)), 
         round(minute(date_add(CreatedDate, INTERVAL '7:30' MINUTE_SECOND)) div 15) 
          * 15, 0)), datetime) as filtertime
 from a
) as withfilter
order by filtertime, abs(timediff(filtertime, CreatedDate)) ;
```

For the other intervals, you have to replace the interval accordingly (so replace `7:30` by half the interval time in minutes, and `15` by the interval time in minutes, so for 30 minute interval it would be:

```
select *
from
(select *,
 convert(timestamp(date(date_add(CreatedDate, INTERVAL '15:00' MINUTE_SECOND)), 
         maketime(hour(date_add(CreatedDate, INTERVAL '15:00' MINUTE_SECOND)), 
         round(minute(date_add(CreatedDate, INTERVAL '15:00' MINUTE_SECOND)) div 30) 
          * 30, 0)), datetime) as filtertime
 from a
) as withfilter
order by filtertime, abs(timediff(filtertime, CreatedDate)) ;
```

(and `30:00` and `60` for the hourly interval).

This will basically round your `CreatedDate` to the closest whole 15/30/60 minutes and order it by the timedifference to that. It will always round up, so a `CreatedDate` `2016-05-20 09:15:00` will be rounded to `2016-05-20 09:30:00` for a 30 minute interval, not to `2016-05-20 09:00:00`.

You might want to take a direct look at the result to understand the final view; for your example data, e.g. `2016-05-20 09:18:40`, it will first calculate the filtertimes `2016-05-20 09:15:00`, `2016-05-20 09:30:00` and `2016-05-20 09:00:00` for the 3 queries 15 minutes, 30 minutes and 1 hour. It will then order it according to their distance to these times (3:40min, 11:20min and 18:40min).

Your reportfilter will have to use the `filtertime` instead of the `CreatedDate` time, and you have to add the minutes to compare to `fromtime`:

```
var report = _reportRepository.FindBy(a => a.Fridge.FridgeIdentity == fridgeIdentity 
   && a.filtertime.Year == fromTime.Year 
   && a.filtertime.Month == fromTime.Month 
   && a.filtertime.Day == fromTime.Day 
   && a.filtertime.Hour == fromTime.Hour
   && a.filtertime.Minute == fromTime.Minute).FirstOrDefault();
```